# Will social networking sites create fake people using AI?

Tags: near-future, artificial-intelligence, social-media

After further development in AI, will social networking sites create fake accounts like humans using AI and make this AI's to talk/chat to real people?

They might do this to get money through ads and make people addicted to their sites.

As many people might share / chat less in the future, will the sites come up with idea? Will it work for them?

Comment: Dating sites already do this

Comment: Spammers already do this. Why bother manually creating profiles and posts when software can do this for you far more quickly?

Comment: For an example of a forum-based spam automation system see [xRumer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XRumer)

Comment: i was thinking like in very large scale of fake people accounts , case like number of fake accounts run by AI  , will out number the number of real people..

Comment: How do we know you're not a bot anyway ?

Comment: So basically...NPCs?

Comment: They have been around for 50 years already. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA

Comment: Goes all the way back to [Alen Turning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Turing) and his [AI test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test) that centered around fooling a human. Some think he overestimated how smart computers could ever be.  I think he under estimated how stupid us humans are.

Comment: @J.Chomel There's little distinction in the SE system between helpful bots and helpful humans. Ask an employee if you want access to the data, but they'll probably (read: almost definitely) say no.

Comment: Why do they need to be created by the site itself?  A real ASI might create a flood or real-looking accounts for it's own social engineering purposes.

Comment: AI is overkill on a social networking site. A random meme selector is sufficient for all practical purposes.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

### Its already happening

> Hello dear,
>
> I can see you logged to this site and I want to tell you, that I am 18 year old girl and totally not experienced in Worldbuilding, *giggles*
>
> I am searching guy who is gifted in building worlds. If you know what I mean.
>
> We can chat online, one to one on this video chat site. And I will show you all my Worldbuilding secrets!
>
> Follow [this spam link](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com) to know more

If you haven't been approached by a young girl wanting sex online yet, you haven't used the Internet long enough...

- Spammers use this technique to attract people to unzip their pants ... and pick up credit cards to see more!
- Dating sites are already creating fake profiles to attract more users.
- Facebook Messenger already offers handy chat bots to provide you entertainment. Just pay $0.99 for some spicy chatbot experience.

One of [core human needs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maslow's_hierarchy_of_needs) is to love and being loved. And people are willing to pay money for that feeling.

So, I would say it is *a very realistic scenario!*

Comment: please , don't click on the spam link in the answer ..

Comment: The spam link goes to a very dangeous time-consuming site.

Comment: Another real world example: http://fortune.com/2016/07/10/ashley-madison-chatbots/

Comment: "If you haven't been approached by a young girl wanting sex online yet, you haven't used the Internet long enough..."

I think "young girl" belongs in scare quotes, as it's unlikely most of them are, in fact, young or girls.

Comment: @MontyHarder something like "young "girl""?

Comment: @AlexP I dunno, [that website isn't that bad](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LuredIntoATrap)

Comment: @JoshPart It's so fake, even the quote marks probably aren't real: "''""young" "girl""''"

Comment: @Yakk Well played. Those who escape siren song of the spam link, might fall for your link, and be led to even more devastating site. There should be trigger warning on links like that. They will ruin your life!

Comment: Oh god, I clicked the link. I'm trapped forever.

Comment: How does the fake accounts with dating sites work? If you match, then what? Does the account simply never respond, or...?

Comment: @DevourerOfStars No, most of the time the account initiate to message you first, then immediately invite you to their live webcam url link. It may really linked to a real live webcam url, but then you need purchase membership to see. Alone and horny AF you will think at least twice before logic kick in and decline the offer.

Answer (score 15):

If you're interested, I'll link to a social networking group with an interesting spin (in beta): **your AI counterpart**.

This particular social network has an AI component that learns how you interact with their systems; it learns your interests through how/what you post, when you're most likely to post, etc. Then even when you're offline, your **counterpart** will be active on the social network. As you train your counterpart, it learns how to more closely imitate your online habits.

This is a more 'intelligent' than chat bots or spammers, and indeed their uses are rather different. 
Personally, I think the idea of a counterpart intriguing. At the philosophical conclusion, you'd have a 'digital' (AI) you, with real experience interacting in your social network. Implications of mass adoption would be...slightly freaky.

https://www.eter9.com/auth/login

Comment: Oh good my aunt can start spamming low-res, poorly sourced political jpegs 24/7!

Answer (score 7):

Pavel mentioned AI programmers who want your money. There are also people who want your vote, or [influence public opinion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitterbot). It is an interesting question if the networking sites *themselves* are complicit with this, or if they are merely basking in the advertising revenue.

Getting to fictional worlds, it would be easy to imagine communities with AIs who greatly outnumber the humans and give each human a [filter bubble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_bubble) with lots of supportive friends.

Answer (score 4):

The AI's will be used on social media for increasingly diverse purposes. Spam, fishing and advertisement are only the tip of the iceberg. And possibly the less interesting cases.

As evermore sophisticated AI mine social media the people who want manipulate that data will build increasingly sophisticated AI pretending to be almost normal people. Who happen to like Coca-Cola.

As privacy enthusiasts acquire better tin foil they will release AI that mask their actions. 9/10 users of my network are not furries.

As the social sciences becomes Science AI will be made to allow testing hypotheses. "Our study found on average 10% more people were 8% more depressed to find 50% or more of their friends were actually AI than predicted by the Smith[2] model. Also we are jerks."